# Pasting multi-line text into text fields shows as really tiny font

Tags: bug, ios-app

I agree it doesn’t matter in the end - but it makes editing the text really difficult!

- Simply typing or hitting Return doesn’t fix it.
- Pressing one of the formatting buttons (e.g. **B**, *I*):

  - ...*inside* the small text makes **everything** small;
  - ...*outside* the small text makes everything normal sized.

And then you have to go back and delete the inserted formatting characters.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPad Pro (12.9 inch) 1G (Cellular)
- OS Version: Version 11.4 (Build 15F79)